# tracking hadoop file upload status via web progress bar?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, progress

I want to design a web project, when users upload file to hadoop hdfs,users can see their upload status via web. Is there any simple java api?

Can anyone help?

Right now I only know the way,how to use api to upload file to hdfs.

```
public synchronized static void upload(FileSystem fs, String local,
        String remote) {
    // Path home = fs.getHomeDirectory();
    Path workDir = fs.getWorkingDirectory();
    Path dst = new Path(workDir + "/" + remote);
    Path src = new Path(local);
    try {
        fs.copyFromLocalFile(false, true, src, dst);
        log.info("upload " + local + " to  " + remote + " successed. ");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("upload " + local + " to  " + remote + " failed :"
                + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find [FileStatus](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) class useful. Through this class you can get almost all the necessary information which your user might wanna know, like getting the access time of the file, modification time of the file, length of the file etc etc.

And, since you are talking about a web app, I would recommend you to have a look at the [WebHDFS REST API](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html). It allows you to submit a GET HTTP request which will send a [FileStatus JSON object](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#GETFILESTATUS) in response. You could then easily use this JSON object to present the status to your user through a web page.

HTH